# How to remove the error message in log file of latex

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, arxiv, bbl

I am using overleaf. I need bbl file to upload the paper in arxiv. I also know that I can get bbl file by clicking the bottom part of the log files in overleaf. I used the Bibtex for reference. But every time I try to compile, it is showing some error in log and out put file. I want to remove this errors. please help. the screenshot is given below.

[image: undefined controled sequence]

[image]

Comment: check your bib file it has an undefined command `\mathplus` perhaps it should be simply `+`

Comment: U+2009 is a thin space (after the A. on the line shown), delete it and replace by a normal space

Comment: Adding the code would certainly help us identify the other errors. For example, the last one is happening in the preamble, maybe you can paste that?